# How to bind control to the current row in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to bind control to the current row in DataGrid?

Comment: I think you could give more information about what you need to do, and what your problem is =)

Comment: What are you currently binding your DataContext to? are you using a ViewModel or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{Binding /} binds to the current item in the data context (when it's a collection).

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the `SelectedItem` property of your DataGrid.

Comment: Isn't there a way to bind directly to items collection?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided us with a lot of information, but I thought I would share my solution with you.

Although keep in mind that this is based on the `Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

A good video introduction to `MVVM` available here:
http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

Sample code (for MVVM) here:

```
// XAML
<DataGrid ...SomeCode... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

// Inside my ViewModel I have:
private object _SelectedItem;
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return this._SelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            this._SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(SelectedItemProperty));
        }
    }
}

// To resolve the SelectedItem you can use the following
var item = (MyNamespace.MyDataSource)SelectedItem;
```

Although you may want to double check that you're getting passed the correct datatype. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
string ID=dataGridView1.Row[i].Cell["id"].Value.ToString();

// Now you can adopt the table value to your query strin
string strData="SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter ("select * from Table1 Where ID='"+ID+"',cn);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

//Now bind the data to corresponding controls.
txtID.Text=dt.Row[0]["ID"].ToString();


//Happy Coding
```